# RGB node not working on mesh, 'ghosting' artefacts of the chosen color instead

Tags: node-editor, shaders, color

I just completed [Blender Guru's gumdrop tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52UYqe3zdxQ&ab_channel=BlenderGuru), followed his video step by step but the color of the main cube (the gumdrop) keeps it's neutral coloring, only showing my chosen color (red) in weird shapes above the mesh like a ghosting bug.

[image]

Is there a way to know what is going on, and how to solve it? I'm using Blender 2.93.

Thanks!

Comment: Andrew uses a volume absorption node like you do, however, when he views it, he is using Cycles Rendering engine. You can tell by the selected one of the 3 preview mode selection "circles" at the top right of your viewport that you are in Material Preview mode, which uses the EEVEE render engine for previews, so even if you are Using Cycles to render, you will not see the gumdrop properly in this view. Volumetrics in EEVEE always take the shape of the bounding box of the volume (usually a cube). Either press Z in the viewport and select "Rendered" or click the circle farthest to the right.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, Christopher